# ("#" + items).append is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 // `shipment` is unique  number 

        var `shipment` = this.Shipment;
             $('<div id=' + this.Shipment + '>' + this.Shipment +'</div>').click(function () {


                 _Services.invoke({
                     method: 'GetOrdersGrid',
                     data: { ShipmentNumber: shipment },
                     success: function (shipment) {
                         paintOrders(`shipment`);
```

the function gets a number of div and needs to put the TEXT into the div

```
<div id="11626">TEXT</div>
<br>
<div id="12109">TEXT</div>
```

> ERROR: ("#" + items).append is not a function [Break On This Error]
>   ('#' + items).append($(container));

WHEN i use the sollar sign   `$('#' + items).append($(container));`

> ERROR
>   uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]

```
WHEN i use without the #
 $(items).append(container); or  $(items).append($(container));

(this[0].ownerDocument || this[0]).createDocumentFragment is not a function
[Break On This Error] var fragment = (this[0].ownerDocument || this[0]).createDocumentFragment(),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing a `$`

Change

```
('#' + items).append($(container));
```

to

```
$('#' + items).append($(container));
```

Presuming, of course, that you have an element with `id` set to whatever `items` resolves to.

Comment: WHEN i use the sollar sign   $('#' + items).append($(container));
ERROR
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]

Comment: Your `items` must be a simple string, not an object. What are you passing to the `paintOrders` function?

Comment: `items` is an array of ids and not a single one?

Comment: YES 
                     _Services.invoke({
                         method: 'GetOrdersGrid',
                         data: { ShipmentNumber: shipment },
                         success: function (shipments) {
                             paintOrders(shipments);
                          
                         }

Comment: @Kristina88: Try `each`ing over your list and passing each id that way, e.g. `$.each(shipments,function(){ paintOrders(this); });`

Comment: OK i edited my code now there is no items  - just shipment and shipment is string

Answer (score 1):

you're missing the `$`

```
$('#' + items).append($(container));
```

Comment: WHEN i use the Dollar sign   $('#' + items).append($(container));
ERROR
uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$('#' + items).append($(container));` instead of `(items).append($(container));`

// items is unique  number

```
function paintOrders(items) {
    var container = '<div>';
    $.each(items, function () {
        container += 'TEXT' + '<br/>';
    });
    container += '</div>';

    $(items).append($(container));
}
```

Comment: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]

Comment: $(items).append($(container)); - error - (this[0].ownerDocument || this[0]).createDocumentFragment is not a function
[Break On This Error] var fragment = (this[0].ownerDocument || this[0]).createDocumentFragment(),

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
function paintOrders(items) {
  var lastIndex = items.length - 1;
  $.each(items, function (index, item) {
    if (index == lastIndex)
      $('#'+item).append('<div>'+'TEXT'+'</div>');
    else
      $('#'+item).append('<div>'+'TEXT'+'</div>'+'<br/>');
  });
}
```

Maybe this code is not exectly what you need but you might find some leads from it.

Comment: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]